# journalbeat example for shipping logs to Elastic Search in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes

I am looking for a descent example for using [journalbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/current/index.html) for shipping logs of kubernetes cluster to elastic search. I have not been able to find descent example on the internet but no luck. Found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549166/kubernetes-api-failure-403-pods-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountdefau) on stackoverflow but it not working either.

Also found this online [gist](https://gist.github.com/kvaps/b08c77f297c5cab21c237fd821310653) as well but its not working either.

Thanks in advance.

Logs which i am getting from the journalbeat pods are

```sh
2020-06-24T07:47:06.690Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:606    Home path: [/usr/share/journalbeat] Config path: [/usr/share/journalbeat] Data path: [/usr/share/journalbeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/journalbeat/logs]
2020-06-24T07:47:06.692Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:614    Beat ID: 3d77834b-5106-41b1-9634-b7123a8267a5
2020-06-24T07:47:06.692Z        INFO    kubernetes/util.go:71   kubernetes: Using node ip-172-28-20-39 provided in the config
2020-06-24T07:47:06.692Z        INFO    kubernetes/watcher.go:182       kubernetes: Performing a resource sync for *v1.PodList
2020-06-24T07:47:06.704Z        INFO    kubernetes/watcher.go:198       kubernetes: Resource sync done
2020-06-24T07:47:06.704Z        INFO    [seccomp]       seccomp/seccomp.go:124  Syscall filter successfully installed
2020-06-24T07:47:06.704Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:902    Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/usr/share/journalbeat", "data": "/usr/share/journalbeat/data", "home": "/usr/share/journalbeat", "logs": "/usr/share/journalbeat/logs"}, "type": "journalbeat", "uuid": "3d77834b-5106-41b1-9634-b7123a8267a5"}}}
2020-06-24T07:47:06.704Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:911    Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "6f0ec01a0e57fe7d4fd703b017fb5a2f6448d097", "libbeat": "7.3.0", "time": "2019-07-24T17:25:58.000Z", "version": "7.3.0"}}}
2020-06-24T07:47:06.704Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:914    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":2,"version":"go1.12.4"}}}
2020-06-24T07:47:06.706Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:918    Host info       {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2020-06-19T20:36:38Z","containerized":true,"name":"ip-172-28-20-39","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","::1/128","172.28.20.39/27","2a05:d018:4:e001:e760:7873:756a:bd81/128","fe80::c3:1ff:fe2c:7fce/64","172.17.0.1/16","172.28.22.1/32","172.28.22.10/32","172.28.22.121/32","172.28.22.125/32","172.28.22.101/32","172.28.23.0/32","172.28.23.103/32","172.28.22.66/32","172.28.22.168/32","172.28.23.173/32","172.28.22.74/32","172.28.22.16/32","172.28.22.246/32","172.28.23.87/32","172.28.22.100/32","172.28.22.18/32","172.28.23.239/32","172.28.23.179/32","172.28.23.211/32","172.28.23.27/32","172.28.23.245/32","172.28.22.2/32","172.28.23.62/32","172.28.22.3/32","172.28.23.180/32","172.28.23.197/32","172.28.22.194/32","172.28.23.232/32","172.28.24.0/32","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64","fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64"],"kernel_version":"5.6.14-300.fc32.x86_64","mac":["02:c3:01:2c:7f:ce","02:42:b1:54:ad:51","12:40:12:32:af:9a","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee","ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee"],"os":{"family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"7 (Core)","major":7,"minor":6,"patch":1810,"codename":"Core"},"timezone":"UTC","timezone_offset_sec":0,"id":"ec276b3dc273bbf21294b9b4cdfbde57"}}}
2020-06-24T07:47:06.706Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:947    Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"permitted":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/usr/share/journalbeat", "exe": "/usr/share/journalbeat/journalbeat", "name": "journalbeat", "pid": 1, "ppid": 0, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter","no_new_privs":true}, "start_time": "2020-06-24T07:47:05.820Z"}}}
2020-06-24T07:47:06.706Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:292    Setup Beat: journalbeat; Version: 7.3.0
2020-06-24T07:47:06.706Z        INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:178      Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'journalbeat-7.3.0' as ILM is enabled.
2020-06-24T07:47:06.706Z        INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:170     Elasticsearch url: http://elasticsearch.domain.com:9200
2020-06-24T07:47:06.707Z        INFO    kubernetes/watcher.go:242       kubernetes: Watching API for resource events
2020-06-24T07:47:06.707Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/module.go:97   Beat name: ip-172-28-20-39
2020-06-24T07:47:06.707Z        WARN    [cfgwarn]       beater/journalbeat.go:53        EXPERIMENTAL: Journalbeat is experimental.
2020-06-24T07:47:06.710Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:421    journalbeat start running.
2020-06-24T07:47:06.710Z        INFO    [journalbeat]   beater/journalbeat.go:91        journalbeat is running! Hit CTRL-C to stop it.
2020-06-24T07:47:06.710Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
2020-06-24T07:47:36.712Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20,"time":{"ms":26}},"total":{"ticks":40,"time":{"ms":47},"value":40},"user":{"ticks":20,"time":{"ms":21}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1024,"soft":1024},"open":7},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"fac99eb5-0c8e-4ff0-98a6-7e151746b223","uptime":{"ms":30030}},"memstats":{"gc_next":4194304,"memory_alloc":2138408,"memory_total":5266480,"rss":30846976},"runtime":{"goroutines":18}},"journalbeat":{"journals":{"journal_0":{"path":"LOCAL_SYSTEM_JOURNAL"}},"libbeat":{"output":{"type":"elasticsearch"},"pipeline":{"clients":1}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":2},"load":{"1":0.21,"15":0.1,"5":0.11,"norm":{"1":0.105,"15":0.05,"5":0.055}}}}}}}
```

Comment: What have you tried? what errors have you encountered? where is your cluster deployed ?

Comment: @paltaa, i have added the logs above. please check. I have tried using the yaml provided in the stackoverflow question given above. The cluster is deployed using https://github.com/poseidon/typhoon

Comment: Logs says its running, so what is the problem? you cannot see them in elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes @paltaa, I am not able to see them in elastic search.